# How do I turn off environment/world lighting in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

Here is the manual on [Environment Lighting](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/world/ambient_light.html?highlight=environment%20lighting)

My version of Blender does not have a widget for environment lighting under the world tab.  I've disabled all lights in my render, but it's still not pitch black.

How do I disable the default environment lighting?

Comment: Manual page you're referring to is about Blender Internal (the information there is not outdated), the screenshot you give in the answer is about Cycles. And this question is *very* engine dependant... So what render engine this aswer is intended for ?

Comment: Cycles, I'll update the question title.  Honestly, it seems a pretty honest mistake.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the background to use nodes and then remove the link.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If your world still has lighting with everything removed, go to the `World` tab in the `Properties` Panel and set the `Color` attribute of the `Surface` Widget to pitch black.  This will remove all world lighting and make the backdrop for any renders which show open space to that color.

In short `Properties > World > Surface > Color > Black`

[image: the above instructions]