# No lights in scene, still lighting up

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I am making a house in Blender Cycles. In rendered mode, all shaders are somehow visible, even though I don't use any lamps. I do have an environment texture, however it shouldn't light up the inside of the house. Especially when there are no windows. Even if I set the background strength to 0, it still lights up the inside and outside of the house.

So now, if I add any lamps, I has nearly no impact on shadows, shaders, reflections etc.
What could be wrong with my scene?

Let me know if you have any questions on my settings that might help you find the problem.

File: https://www.mediafire.com/?cs3dl1xx56ih60a

These are the world settings: [image]

For the Ambient occlusion I always use this node: [image]

It usually works fine.

Comment: As far as I know, only lamps, environment textures and meshes with a material that uses an Emission shader can add light to a scene. Can you post a .blend?

Comment: yea sure, moment....

Comment: Possibly [Ambient Occlusion](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/render/cycles/world.html#ambient-occlusion).

Comment: It'll take a while, I use Mediafire to upload because the file is more than 30Mb.

Comment: here it is, in my question.

Comment: Please show screenshots of the world settings if you can do so easily. You should strip the file down to less...no reason to upload the entire thing. Most likely, you'll find the problem while doing this...

Comment: Well it's already uploaded sir.

Comment: It is not good practice to upload it to another site. We use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend files. If it doesn't fit there, there isn't a reason for most people to take the time to look at it. I would highly recommend doing what I suggested, but it's up to you. I could quite easily answer your question, but I won't be downloading a large file from mediafire right now...

Comment: Well, it was the ambient occlusion. Thank you Leander.

Comment: @Leander Can we give this question an answer? Seems like the issue has been resolved. Maybe explain how AO can cause this? It may benefit other readers.

Comment: I think Leander should. He kind of solved my problem. Others can of course post one too, but I will mark Leander's as solved.

Comment: AO is calculated to illuminate a scene in a non-reality sort of way, therefore it lightens things that would normally have no light, and falls off where surfaces meet other surfaces (that's why it is distance based). Its basic logic principal is that dirt collects in corners & wear + tear is less in corners meaning corners are darker/saturated. The inverse is also true the open areas don't collect as much dirt & they get more wear + tear, so they end up lighter / desaturated.

Comment: AO can also be mixed with PBR (cycles) workflows, to help sell the reality of a scene where you don't have enough light. This can be done globally to the scene such as was the case by checking it in the World section, or it can be applied per material using the 'Pointiness' output from the 'Geometry' input node. Hope that helps get you started into approaching AO.

Comment: This might be overstepping a little bit (as a more accurate approach would be to go check out some of Troy_s 's info on colorspace - Adrew Price over at Blender Guru did a pretty good breakdown of how to breakdown his work for getting started with it in Blender), but for photoreal - colorspace reasons, AO can be used to mimic the washing out of colors, instead of just upping their brightness when hit with light. If you would rather be more accurate check out the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9AT7H4GGrA)

Comment: Try going to the 'world' settings and set 'surface' to black.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Objects may appear illuminated, if ...

- they are illuminated by [lamp](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/lamps.html#lamps) objects
- they are illuminated by mesh lights with [emission](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/emission.html#emission-node) shaders
- they are emitting light completely or partially, if they have an emission shader
- the wrongheaded use of an *Add Shader* in a material
- they are illuminated by the [world](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/world.html#surface) ([background](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/background.html#background-node) shader)
- [ambient occlusion](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/world_settings.html#ambient-occlusion) is activated

The Ambient Occlusion is activated in your scene.
[image]
Uncheck **Ambient Occlusion** to disable it.
It is found under the World section of the [Properties Panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/properties_editor.html).

Also make sure no light emitting objects are hidden by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to unhide all objects.

Comment: I didn't completely turn off the AO because there is a bit of an outside scene as well. I do want clear shadows there with the environment texture.

Comment: Nice answer. You might want to add that Add Shaders can also cause illumination. [Here is an example .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2867/) of a "light" created with only Add Shaders chained to a standard Diffuse.

Comment: @Mentalist Great example. Will add, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

This link solved it for me: Had the same Problem. Light in the scene even though I had no lights placed.

[How do I turn off environment/world lighting in Blender Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69014/how-do-i-turn-off-environment-world-lighting-in-blender-cycles)

Go to *World Tab*. Then to *Surface* option. Then pick use nodes.

Then you can see *Background* written on the button that appears. Or you choose *Background* under the shaders that appear when you click your the option under *Surface*.

So you pick *Background* as the shader of your *Surface* option. And then comes the trick, you click it again.

And then as the shader you can choose: *Remove*. That solved it for me. Under the link is a video that shows it.

Comment: on 2.83.12 I had to disable the World/Surface/UseNodes and then set the color to pure black 0,0,0, and it worked, thx! I think that version comes with a default node for world that has dark grey light.