# Blender Cycles Diffuese Material - Why it stays so light?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Blender Cycles Diffuese Material - Why it stays so light? I can't figure out how to get id darker!

Thanks, 
Manolo

[image]

Comment: [Rela](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/74873/30849) - [ted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66662/objects-can-be-seen-after-turning-off-all-lights-how-to-turn-off-ambient-light/66684#66684).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a scene with a light that is set at a low intensity:

[image]

Here's the same scene with a brighter light:

[image]

Here's the same scene with a much brighter light:

[image]

Cycles uses lights that try to resemble how light works in the real world:
The brighter the source, the more light that will be reflected by the object, making it brighter.

The "color" of a diffuse object thus depends on the light it reflects.

Other factors that might be affecting your scene:

- The brightness of the environment (world)
- The Exposure setting in the film section (default is 1 don't change it unless you have a very good reason, and know what you are doing)
- The Exposure setting in the Color Management section (read: [Which Exposure control to use?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13678/which-exposure-control-to-use))
- The settings for color management:

  The view transform used. (Read: [Render with a wider dynamic range in cycles to produce photorealistic looking images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im))

  [image]

  Any changes in the settings for gamma or the use of curves.
- The use of ambient occulsion (in cycles you don't need it. Read: [Ambient occlusion in Principled BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101234/ambient-occlusion-in-principled-bsdf) and [Adding Ambient Occlusion to Material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46287/adding-ambient-occlusion-to-material/46290#46290))

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware Point/Spot/Area lamp, with **the same** strength and world color nodes values, makes the object darker either. In this case you need much higher lamp Strength value to make it brighter. My experience shows Hemi/Sun lamps with strength 3 work fine