# Material preview background color - Blender Cycles

Tags: materials

i can't figure out how to change Material preview background  color in Blender Cycles.

I need to switch from 1 to 2.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Why do you **need** that?

Answer (score 4):

The Material Preview window uses the view transforms set in the color management section.

[image]

Comment: I suppose it can be the origin of my problem. The material on the left window should be red and not pink (or bright red, as you like). I'm trying to see a red color in the material preview and not a pink (or similar). I think i touched something that doesn't allow me to get full color materials when i create a new material.

Comment: Please re-read the [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/109465/1853) to your previous question.- Including the links (in blue text).

Answer (score 0):

I also would be interested, WHY you would need that. But here's a quick explanation:

The brightness is dependent on your color management settings. 
You can change View, Exposure, Gamma and Look.
But actually, I wouldn't do that just to change the material preview. 
These are important aspects for the overall look of your scene.

A straight up change of the background color isn't possible, afaik.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Unless you have a compelling reason (and know what you are doing) I would advise to leave those settings untouched. You'd get more control using proper material settings and proper lighting.

Comment: My problem is this:

in nodes i say i want a RED MATERIAL... BUT the result is PINK!

WHY?

WHAT did i touch?

Thanks again.

Comment: See image up. Now i try bstnhnsl suggestion. Thanks

Comment: bstnhnsl you got it!

Comment: @M.Terranova If you are using filmic blender just set the view to "base contrast".please read the following link so that you understand how to use the filmic blender color management settings: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im and https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender