# How not to cast a shadow on an object?

Tags: light

[image]

I don't want to see the shadow cast on the wall like the circled one with red pen the picture. How can I cancel such light effect?

I found an answer that said to go the "word" and "surface" to remove it. I am not sure that it's the same thing (link: [How do I turn off environment/world lighting in Blender Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69014/how-do-i-turn-off-environment-world-lighting-in-blender-cycles))

but I did not see the "surface" option in my "world" column.

Thank you for helping me, I really appreciate it

Comment: That's not a shadow, It's probably related to camera clipping, which means that your object is too big. You can either make the object smaller or increase the camera's clipping distance

Answer (score 1):

Its not a shadow.Its scene or camera's clipping value that you need to adjust. To change scene's clip value,increase the value circled in the below pic:[image]

And to change camera's clip value,increase the value circled in the below pic:[image]